# jQuery Selector : Selecting element, without a particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I recently started using jquery and stuck with element selection.

The HTML code looks as below:

```
 <ul id="wantsAndNeedsPanelBar">

        <li><img src="../resources/css/images/2_imp.png"> #= data[i].subCategories[j].elements[k].text#</li>

        <li><img src="../resources/css/images/1_imp.png"> #= data[i].subCategories[j].elements[k].text#</li>

        <li>#= data[i].subCategories[j].elements[k].text#</li>
```

On check/uncheck of a checkbox, I want to hide all list elements without img.
I tried below code without much success.

```
 if (e.checked){
       $("#wantsAndNeedsPanelBar li").show();
       $("#wantsAndNeedsPanelBar img").show();
   }else {

       $("#wantsAndNeedsPanelBar li").hide();
    }
```

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should hide ***all list elements without img***

```
$("#wantsAndNeedsPanelBar li:not(:has(img))").hide();
```

Here we have used [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector, [`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, Have a look at the docs to know more about it.